# How to convert the Bitmap image to .pcx format for printing image in Zebra Printer

Tags: android, image, printing, bitmap, zebra-printers

I have an issue while printing the image in Zebra printer along with some text. Sources said that for printing the image we have to convert the image to .pcx format. I could not find the way, how to convert the image to .pcx in android.

Can any one know please post the solution here on how to print the image along with some text from Zebra  Printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use GIMP and ImageMagick for static images, if you want dynamic images I suggest you try another method to send image data.

[GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/):
Convert the image to "Indexed mode"
Image->Mode->Indexed->Use black and white (1-bit) palette.
Save as .bmp

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php):
Then use imagemagick's 'convert' program to convert from .bmp to .pcx
i.e. convert source.bmp target.pcx

Then you have 1-bit pcx-file you can include in your android app.

Comment: Hi Christian A.M, thanks for the immediate response. Could you please post a source code of converting to .pcx format and also how to use this pcx image for printing

Answer (score 2):

Zebra provides an [Android SDK](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/link-os/link-os-sdk.html) that will convert graphics to PCX for you