# Does someone successfully printed a Image to zebra Bluetooth printer using blue_thermal_printer in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bluetooth, thermal-printer

I want to print a barcode to my zebra Bluetooth printer but my only sulotion is to print a barcode using  image but the printer is beeping can't print anything.

```
  String pathImage;

  initSavetoPath()async{
    //read and write
    //image max 300px X 300px
    final filename = 'yourlogo.png';
    var bytes = await rootBundle.load("assets/images/yourlogo.png");
    String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    writeToFile(bytes,'$dir/$filename');
    setState(() {
      pathImage='$dir/$filename';
      sample(pathImage);
    });
  }


//triggerd on button pressed
sample(String pathImage) async {
    bluetooth.isConnected.then((isConnected) {
      if (isConnected) {
        bluetooth.printNewLine();
        bluetooth.printCustom("barcode Sample",3,0);
        bluetooth.printNewLine();
        bluetooth.printImage(pathImage);

    });
  }
```

Comment: What is the detailed model number? And do you print with other applications or tools?

Comment: zebra ez320, yes it is printing successfully using an app i downloaded on playstore

Comment: Please request a developer tool from these pages. [EZ320 MOBILE PRINTER SUPPORT](https://www.zebra.com/gb/en/support-downloads/printers/mobile/ez320.html), [REQUEST DEVELOPER TOOLS FOR BARCODE PRINTERS](https://www.zebra.com/ap/en/support-downloads/printer-software/by-request-software.html)

Comment: You will need to convert the image file to .pcx format. Refer to this article. [How to convert the Bitmap image to .pcx format for printing image in Zebra Printer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19003348/9014308), [CPCL MANUAL FOR ZEBRA MOBILE PRINTERS](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/cpcl-manual-for-zebra-mobile-printers.html)